# How to set tooltip z-index greater than kendo grid header?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am using kendo grid for the data and for one field i am using angular tooltip  so i have one issue with tooltip,In first row tooltip is hiding under the kendo grid header all other rows are good with the z-index. So i want to add z-index to this field so it can be visible on first row as well. How to achieve that task using css ?

config.js

```
{
    field: 'locationComments',
    title: 'Location Comments',
    width: '210px',
    filterable: false,
    sortable: false,
    template: function () {
    return '<textarea  '+
    'data-tooltip-html-unsafe="<div>{{512 - this.dataItem.locationComments.length}} characters left</div>" '+
    'tooltip-trigger="{{{true: \'focus\', false: \'never\'}[this.dataItem.locationComments.length >= 0 || this.dataItem.locationComments.length == null ]}}" '+
    'tooltip-placement="top" dropdown-append-to-body="true" tooltip-class = "bluefill" '+
    'maxlength="512" #=gridStatus=="NOT_EDITABLE" ? "disabled" : "" # type="text" id="locationComments" name="locationComments" ng-model="this.dataItem.locationComments" ></textarea>';
}
```

main.css

```
.k-grid-content table tr td textarea.toolTipIndex {
    z-index:10002;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the tooltip attribute tooltip-append-to-body="true" so that it is outside the dom that is keeping it from popping over.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Thanks for the response but i am still trying to understand why we are using attribute dropdown-append-to-body="true" , i added as attribute but still dont see the tooltip. Please check my question i edited according to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. typing too fast. try tooltip-append-to-body='true'

Comment: still No luck after adding tooltip-append-to-body='true'   :(